# Disable Extension on clicking the icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension which can be disabled with a simple click on the browser action icon. I want to give the users this option because the extension raises a javascript alert when the alarm is triggered. The problem is that even after clearing the alarms, I am seeing alerts being raised. Also the icon click, which I want to work as a switch, isn't working as intended.

I have declared background.js as my background javascript file in manifest.json

```js
"background": {
    "scripts": ["alert.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/green.png",
    "default_action": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Toggle Productiwitty"
}
```

background.js

```js
var ExtensionOn = true;

function SwitchOn(e)
{
    chrome.alarms.create("Alarm", {delayInMinutes: 0.1, periodInMinutes: 1} );
}

function SwitchOff(e) 
{
    chrome.alarms.clear("Alarm");
}

function showpopup()
{
    alert("Inside function showpopup");
    console.log("alert shown");
}

function click(e)
{
    if(ExtensionOn)
    {
        SwitchOff();
        console.log("switched off");
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "Off"});
    }
    else if(!ExtensionOn)
    {
        SwitchOn();
        console.log("switched on");
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "ON"});
        // Replace 15.0 with user selected time in minutes  
    }
    //Toggle ExtensionOn
    ExtensionOn = ~ ExtensionOn;
}

if(ExtensionOn)
{
    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(showpopup);
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(click);
```

My "default_action": "popup.html" calls popup.js which creates the alarm

```js
chrome.alarms.create("Alarm", {delayInMinutes: 0.1, periodInMinutes: 1} );
```

The idea is that once the extension is loaded, it should show a popup every 1 minute and if you click the icon, the extension gets disabled temporarily. On clicking the icon again, the same alert will be raised periodically.

Comment: "Disabling the extension" is different than "clicking the browser action to toggle a behavior".

Comment: @Teepeemm Well technically the toggle function is disabling it. In the developer options when you want to switch off your extension, you uncheck the enable button. So antonym of enable is disable. Suggest a better and more relevant title and I will edit my post :)

Comment: And why are you using a persistent background page?

Comment: The checkbox in `chrome://extensions` will enable or disable the extension.  Having a binary behavior on your browser action is completely different.  If you think about it, you're not really trying to "disable" anything.  You're really wanting to have the browser action have two different outcomes.  It just so happens that one of those outcomes doesn't do anything.  So I'd call that a separate thing than "disabling" an extension.

Comment: @DanielHerr: Would an event page make more sense here? I am new to Chrome extension development.

Comment: As things are, an event page wouldn't work, because when it reloads, `ExtensionOn` would get reset to `true`.  So if you let the event page unload, then click the browser action, you'd always end up with the extension in the same state.  I think you'd want to look into storage if you really want to make it an event page.  The other possibility would be to use `chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText` to get what state your extension is in, and not use `ExtensionOn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
ExtensionOn = true
> true
ExtensionOn = ~ ExtensionOn
> -2
Boolean(ExtensionOn)
> true
```

If you want to toggle a boolean, use `!`, not `~`.

```js
if(ExtensionOn)
{
    chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(showpopup);
}
```

This is only called once, when a page first loads.  If the extension isn’t on at that time, the listener won’t be added, and the function will never be called.  I’d recommend moving the `if` test into `showpopup`.

Comment: Adding the if clause to the showpopup function seems to have solved the problem. However, the reason why I am not getting alerts anymore is because I am not showing alerts if the ExtensionOn variable is set to false, but the alarms have not been cleared and are still hogging memory. Also, without the if clause in showpopup the same issue persists. 

Thanks for the ! suggestion.

Comment: @Piyush `else if (!ExtensionOn)` won't happen if you still have `~` because `ExtensionOn` will be 1 or -2, either of which are truthy.  But you don't even need it; just use `else` because you want one branch or the other.

Comment: Makes sense. Have replaced else if with else and ~ with !. However, the popup still shows when ExtensionOn = false without the if(ExtensionOn) condition in showpopup() function. I am marking the answer as accepted because it is working. However, I am unable to clear the alarm when the extension icon is clicked. The goal here is to click the icon and clear alarms and then click on the icon again and generate a new alarm.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your code now is.  The only thing I can think of would be to take what you've learned here and create a new question (possibly referring back to this one).  (Please don't edit the current question to make what we've done to help to be redundant.)

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled

`chrome.management.setEnabled(ExtId, true/false, callback)`

But i'm not sure disabling the extension is what you actually want to do,
once you disable it you have to go to chrome://extension and manually re-enable it.

Comment: If you have ever used the Adblock extension, you have the option of clicking on it which disables the extension and then you can click it back to get it to working again.